# How to make a button don't overlap the EditText when keyboard showing up?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

There is a bottom_sheet_behavior button at the bottom of the screen, and when the keyboard shows up, it shows on the top of the keyboard. I want to keep it this way. 
The problem is, when I tab the EditText to input, the button shows on the top of the keyboard, which overlaps half of the EditText like this:
[image]
 So I want the EditText automatically scroll up a bit more to show itself wholy. I tried in MainActivity.java onCreate() {

```
mEditText.scrollTo(0, mEditText.getTop());
```

and tried

```
mEditText.scrollTo(0, mEditText.getTop() + 20); 
// to try if it will scroll up more in this way. it didn't.
```

but the edittext is still half overlapped exactly as before when the keyboard appears. I guess I invoke the method in a wrong way?

The soft keyboard is not overlapping with the EditText, but the bottom button is. Is there anyway to programmatically scroll the EditText to right above the button when the keyboard showing?

the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.robyn.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> // i tried make this "adjustPan" it behaves the same.
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.robyn.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="Input:"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:text="save"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // bottom button overlaps edittext

    private EditText mEditText;
    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
        mEditText.scrollTo(0, mEditText.getTop());
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "adjustPan" will hide the app button which shows on keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paddingBottom to the parent of ScrollView (LinearLayout).
If Button height = 50dp, set paddingBottom="50dp" to LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Input:"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:text="save"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```